# Open web browser on host machine via private ip after installing software on Linux server

Tags: linux, ssh, rhel, browser, redis

I need to open a web browser on the host machine. I am given a private IP address after installing software on a Red Hat Enterprise 7.9 Linux server.

Here are the steps I have taken so far:

- SSH into server using a 'SSH name@serverAddress'
- I follow the instructions and install Redis Enterprise for Red Hat
  Enterprise 7.9
- It is a success and gives me the following instructions inside the
  Linux terminal where I installed the software.

```
[!] Please logout and login again to make sure all environment changes are applied.
[!] Point your browser at the following URL to continue:
[!] https://privateIpAddress:8443
```

I would now like to follow these instructions. Where do I go to open this browser?
If you would like the full instructions, they can be found here.

I am on step 2: set up a cluster.
https://docs.redislabs.com/latest/rs/getting-started/

My current thoughts (very possible they are wrong):

I return to where the terminal where I originally SSH into the Linux box and type some command. Possibly something like

```
 ssh -L 127.0.0.1:80:intra.example.com:80 gw.example.com
```

But I do not know what the exact command would be.
Or I do something inside the actual Linux server to open the browser.
I believe the answer is extremely easy and it is escaping me. Otherwise, they would have noted something to the instructions.

once again, the information I have is:

- SSH name@myserveraddress
- and now a private IP:
- https://privateIpAddress:8443

And this obviously does not open on a browser on my local machine.

Let me know if I need to give any more information. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

assuming you starting host is `earth` (the one where you brower open)

you ssh call should be (from `earth`)

```
ssh -L 127.0.0.1:8443:privateIpAddress:8443 name@myserveraddress
```

then, after installation, from `earth`, open a browser to

```
https://127.0.0.1:8443
```

please note

- port 8443 must be free on `earth` (you can check with `netstat -tlp` or `ss -l -4`)
- local port can be change to 9999 for instance (`-L 127.0.0.1:9999:privateIpAddress:8443` and `https://127.0.0.1:9999` )
- port forwarding make sence as a drill or if you can't access directly `privateIpAddress:8443` from `earth` (due to firewalling/DMZ/routing)

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answer. I believe I solved it by being in the terminal

curl privateIp

then went into a browser on my local comp and used the https:serverIPaddress:8443

Comment: well if serverIPaddress:8443 can be accessed  from outside, there is no issue at all.

Comment: Ya. I did not know this. I guess I was completely confused by the instructions provided after the install. I thought it wanted me to access the private IP. Sorry for the confusion.